Question about this adress D8TnJAXML7gEzUdGhY5T7aNfQQXxfr8k5huC6s11ea5R
Today all my coins are transfered to this adress D8TnJAXML7gEzUdGhY5T7aNfQQXxfr8k5huC6s11ea5R.
And it shows this adress owned by SYSTEM PROGRAMM. Do i get stohlen by solona??? All this adress has always more sols and other coins. and still not transfer out. What the hell is this. Can someone explain it to me? I am so sadly now. Thx for any help, guys!
